# problem converting a regular query to parametrized query

Tags: vb.net

I came across this old piece of code that looks like this:

```
        Dim sql As String = "exec wa_vterm_Insert_upd_Purchase_Card @merchant_id = '" & db.SqlSafe(sMerchantID) & "'" &
        ", @reference = '" & db.SqlSafe(reference) & "' " &
        ", @national_tax = " & nationalTax & " " &
        ", @customer_vat_number = '" & db.SqlSafe(customerVatNumber) & "' " &
        ", @discount_amount = " & discountAmount & " " &
        ", @duty_amount = " & dutyAmount & " " &
        ", @vat_invoice_number = '" & db.SqlSafe(vatInvoiceNumber) & "' " &
        ", @vat_tax_amount = " & vatTaxAmount & " " &
        ", @vat_tax_rate = " & vatTaxRate & " " &
        ", @destination_country_code = '" & db.SqlSafe(destCountryCode) & "' "
    Trace.WriteLine(sql, LogLevel.Debug)
    db.ExecuteNonQuery(sql)
```

I am converting this to parameterized query and I coded this:

```
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("wa_vterm_Insert_upd_Purchase_Card", con)

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@merchant_id", sqlDbType:=SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sMerchantID
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@reference", sqlDbType:=SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = reference
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@national_tax", sqlDbType:=SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nationalTax
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@customer_vat_number", sqlDbType:=SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = customerVatNumber
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@discount_amount", sqlDbType:=SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = discountAmount
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@duty_amount", sqlDbType:=SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dutyAmount

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@vat_invoice_number", sqlDbType:=SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = vatInvoiceNumber

    cmd.Parameters.Add(" @vat_tax_amount", sqlDbType:=SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = vatTaxAmount

    cmd.Parameters.Add(" @vat_tax_rate", sqlDbType:=SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = vatTaxRate
    cmd.Parameters.Add(" @destination_country_code", sqlDbType:=SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = destCountryCode

    Try
        cmd.Connection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message & ex.Source, LogLevel.Debug)
    Finally
        cmd.Connection.Close()
    End Try
```

however with the new piece of code I am getting this exception:
"Procedure or function 'wa_vterm_Insert_upd_Purchase_Card' expects parameter '@vat_tax_amount', which was not supplied."

I don't understand why??

Comment: try to remove the space in  cmd.Parameters.Add(" @vat_tax_amount", sqlDbType:=SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = vatTaxAmount

Comment: @raBinn That was it.  Thanks friend.

Comment: @Waddaulookingat - It is worth mentioning that you could save a lot of typing by using the With statement on `cmd.Parameters`.

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestion above the answer was a space in front of the @var_tax_amount